Fluid disappear mid air
I'm learning blender.
As a way to practice animation and physics control, I'm modeling a pancake with honey poured on it.
something like this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqWIAXE30yE
However, I'm having problems with the way fluid simulation is behaving. The fluid just disappears in mid air while it's pouring down. Even if it touches pancake surface, it disappears after a few frames. Could someone please give advises on how I can fix these problems?


Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

The simulation is going crazy on my computer (decreased resolution and domain size before-hand). Maybe try to setup a new domain with fresh settings ? Also, either gravity is way too strong or simulation time is too quick : for me with no viscosity, particles reach the plate in 1/5th of a second, which is way too quick.

i don't know what you did, but i would recommend just deleting your domain (not the cube) and adding it again. Then it works.
Also for honey i would recommend to use viscosity, else it would look more like water.

...before you deleted the domain, the original one in the file used viscosity. But apart from that, even after deleting the domain and adding it again it works as long as you do not use viscosity - the viscosity is the thing that messes everything up when I simulate it.

Thank you everyone, I took all advice. It seems like the viscosity is doing something too, but the Particle Radius was the main source of the problem.
